# How can I draw shapes in Three.js with mouse?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, three.js

I am looking for a way to allow user to draw his own cube, like here (try to draw a cube onto a grid):

https://next.shapesmith.net/ui/tmp_1a43d130-8e44-470e-b597-4747f63f01f9/designs

Screenshot:
[image]

Shapesmith has this solved very good and It's also written with Three.js but it uses Backbone.js and I don't know how to port drawing functionality from their code to my. Shapesmith is open source.
Is it possible to port code from Backbone.js to standard JavaScript application ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you look [Three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/)

I think the code is open source

Comment: Yes I know this Editor. But it doesn't have "drawing" functionality. I just adds the cube to the scene and allows to change parameters. Please take a look at shapesmith.net how their drawing works and it's written in three.js.